# Coq: Defining multiple notations simultaneously

Tags: definition, coq, notation

Is it possible to (somehow) define multiple notations simultaneously, e.g.

```
Notation (A|B) := nat.
```

or

```
Notation B := A
where A := nat.
```

The following works (but is not what I'm looking for; I want a "clean" notation, w/out symbols):

```
Notation "' x" := nat (at level 99).
Check 'A: Set.
Check 'what: Set.
```

Also, if this matters, my actual *definiens* is not `nat` but a longer `ltac: (match ...)`

Comment: I am afraid I can't follow the question in full. Does using `Reserved Notation` help?

Comment: I don't think `Reserved Notation` would help here (I want different *definiendums* while `Reserved Notation` reserves only one)